# Why do broker patterns look so simple?

Tags: design-patterns, uml

I've been learning about the Larman Broker Pattern and have been shown examples which are fairly vague. Here is an example: [image]

Is there any way this can be expanded on in a diagram? I'm not sure where to look for resources.

Comment: I'd say they look simple because they are simple ;-) What would you expect from a pattern? It needs to be simple else it is not usable.

Comment: That's true. I was hoping for more functions in the Relational Brokers.

Comment: In that case you should have taken another wording for your question. Google has quite some resources: http://www.utdallas.edu/~chung/SP/applying-uml-and-patterns.pdf